# What is the Pythonic way of doing this?

Tags: python

I want a list of dicts for some data, I tried doing it this way:

```
dataList = ['Jim    5656    qwgh', 'Tim    5833    qwgh']

dataDictList = [ {'name': data[0], 'sknum': data[1]} for data.split('\t') in dataList ]
```

I get syntax error, which I'm guessing is because 'data.split('\t')' is not working somehow.

I can do this in not so Pythonic way like below, but this is something I don't want to do.

```
dataDictList = []    

for d in dataList:
    data = d.split('\t')
    dataDictList.append({ 'name': data[0], 'sknum': data[1] })
```

I would like to know the reason why the above part shows a syntax error.

Comment: You are accessing "data" but data.split('\t') does not return the variable "data" which has been split.

Comment: maybe is better if you show the `\t` : `dataList = ['Jim\t5656\tqwgh', 'Tim\t5833\tqwgh']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should you *really* want a one-liner:

```
>>> dataList = ['Jim    5656    qwgh', 'Tim    5833    qwgh']
>>> [dict(zip(['name', 'sknum'], s.split())) for s in dataList]
[{'name': 'Jim', 'sknum': '5656'}, {'name': 'Tim', 'sknum': '5833'}]
```

Comment: @StephaneRolland the OP's example doesn't actually contain tabs! But I figure that's a small enough change they can make it as appropriate themselves.

Answer (score 1):

How about using map and split

**code**

```
dataList = ['Jim    5656    qwgh', 'Tim    5833    qwgh']
dataDictList = [ {'name': data[0], 'sknum': data[1]} for data in map(str.split, dataList)]
dataDictList
[{'name': 'Jim', 'sknum': '5656'}, {'name': 'Tim', 'sknum': '5833'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
dataList = ['Jim    5656    qwgh', 'Tim    5833    qwgh']
splitDataList = [data.split('\t') for data in dataList ]

dataDictList = [ {'name': data[0], 'sknum': data[1]} for data in splitDataList ]
```

Comment: But then you have to `str.split` twice!

Comment: Yeah, suppose I have to use 10 times split.

Comment: @StephaneRolland is there any other way to do that as a one liner

Comment: @VigneshKalai  yes, your method with map() :-) I prefer it to mine.